# Using change in one variable (2 timepoints) to predict change in another variable (2 timepoints): latent change models?

Tags: lavaan, growth-model

I have two variables, both measured at two timepoints: before and after an experimental procedure.
I'm expecting that change in one variable from Time 1 to Time 2 will predict change in the other variable from Time 1 to Time 2.

I think that I may be able to test this model with the following code in Lavaan:

```
library(lavaan)
#intercepts
ia =~ 1*a1 + 1*a2
ib =~ 1*b1 + 1*b2
#slopes
sa =~ 0*b1 + 1*b2
sb =~ 0*a1 + 1*a2

#regression
sb ~ sa
```

My question is two-fold:

1. Is this a "latent change model"? I can't find any specific guidance or resources doing something exactly like this. But I think this computes two slopes and uses one slope to predict the other slope.
2. How is this different from extracting the coefficient for each subject, saving that coefficient to the datafile, and then computing a simple fixed effects multiple regression?

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There's a good recent discussion on [Data Methods](https://discourse.datamethods.org/t/using-the-change-in-the-value-of-a-predictor-variable-as-a-parameter-in-a-multivariable-prognostic-model/5313) about strategies for incorporating a change in one variable as a predictor, which might be generalized to your question (predicting a change in another variable) by adding the the second variable baseline as a predictor and possibly also with interactions to predict the second variable post-treatment. However, none of the proposed solutions seem to touch on latent variable modeling for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to define a latent intercept for the "b" pair.  In your current code, `s1` is just a dummy/phantom/single-indicator factor that puts `b2` in latent space.  So you are predicting `b2` rather than change from `b1` to `b2`.

1. I'm pretty sure the LGCM with only 2 occasions would be statistically equivalent to a latent difference/change score (LDS) model, if you fixed the indicators' residual variances to zero.  In that case, the second indicator's variance is composed entirely of (a) the first indicator's variance plus (b) variance in the change score (latent slope).  And the latent intercept is simply the first indicator in latent space, which points to the second indicator, just as the first indicator typically does in a LDS model.

```
a_diff =~ 1*a2 # analogous to "s2" above
a2 ~ 1*a1

a2 ~~ 0*a2

a1 ~~ a1 + a_diff
a_diff ~~ a_diff
```

2. You are describing factor-score regression, which is problematic because estimated factor scores are treated as observed data.  There are some solutions (Croon's correction, `semTools::plausibleValues()`, structural-after-measurement in `lavaan::sam()`: preprint linked below), but I don't see any reason to consider using this approach in your situation.  They can be good alternatives to a big simultaneous SEM when *N* is small or the measurement model fits only approximately well for constructs that otherwise meet all validity criteria.

https://osf.io/pekbm/ (SAM preprint, also discusses Croon's correction)

Comment: thanks for your response.  Just to clarify: Are you suggesting that if I add the intercept for the b pair, the code would be correct? Like this: ```library(lavaan)
#intercept
i =~ 1*a1 + 1*a2 
i2 =~ 1*b1 + 1*b2  
s1 =~ 0*b1 + 1*b2
s2 =~ 0*a1 + 1*a2
#regression
s2 ~ s1 ```. Or are you suggesting that I should replace my code with your version entirely? In which case, I'd need to include the b values as well?

Comment: Just to add the intercept (I edited your post accordingly).  The code I provided was only an LDS model for `a`.

Comment: @Terrence, hey, could you please have a look at a related post ? I'm sure you can reply to my question in 30 seconds.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78071203/latent-change-score-using-lavaan-with-observed-variables-measured-at-two-time-po